# Extract javascript jquery contents form MVC View to standalone .js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to extract some simple content from a MVC View to a separate .js file: `~Scripts/sample.js`.

Initially, in _Layout.cshtml, I have the following contents at the end of the file:

`<script>
    $(function () {
       alert("test");
    }
</script>`

This works fine and a Messagebox is shown.

When I try to extract the Javascript contents to a separate file in `~Scripts/sample.js` this seems to not work anymore.

The whole content of `~Scripts/sample.js` is:

`$(function () {
        alert("test");
    }`

I tried to include is at the end of Layout.cshtml with:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/sample.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="~/Scripts/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but it does not work and a MessageBox is not displayed.

Any idea why this does not work? I want to mention that including the jquery/bootstrap .js files is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem turned out to be the caching of .js files which I had enabled, and an older version of the file was used.

A workaround is to force the browser to only take the latest version, for example:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Shared/sample.js?<"+@DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()+">")"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little adjustment

```
$(function () {
    alert("test");
})
```

it seems to work fine.

Comment: The Problem was the browser caching not taking the latest .js Version. Your answer is also valid that I missed a Paranthesis, but the caching was the main Problem.